# Treasury Bond Yield Curves in R

Tags: programming, fixed-income

Does anyone know if I can access interest rates series from the treasury using R? I tried yahoo! Finance and it doesn't seem to have this kind of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/) package claims to support downloading data from Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis Economic database, which contains plenty of [rates time series](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/22). It should be pretty simple to get them into R using function `getSymbols`, in the same manner as

```
getSymbols("DEXJPUS",src="FRED") # FX rates from FRED
```

Comment: getSymbols("DSG10",src="FRED") # daily ten year treasury yld

Answer (score 3):

Try the Fed's H15 series. Daily data is here, with links to historical: http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/update/

Answer (score 3):

There are some interest rates accessible through the R package [`YieldCurve`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/YieldCurve/YieldCurve.pdf). I don't think they contain the latest available interest rates.

Another alternative is the package [`FRBData`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FRBData/). Using the function `GetInterestRates` you can download various of the latest interest rates published by the FRB.